# I understand b_ matches beta, but why does it also match alpha?

Tags: pattern-matching, filtering

Why does this pick out everything instead of just `beta`?

```
Cases[{alpha, beta, mxyzptlk}, b_]
```

In a function you have to match the lead character. `f[x_] := x^2`, but `f[x_] := p^2` doesn't do anything. Anyway, it would be very useful to have an "anything" character that is like * in Windows. Is there such a thing where a* would match `alpha`?

Comment: To close voter: since OP also asks about how to implement wildcard for pattern-matching, I think it's not proper to classify this question as simple mistake.

Answer (score 10):

You've severely misunderstood how pattern matching of *Mathematica* works. `_` is not [wildcard character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character) like `?` or `*`. A simple example to tear off your illusion:

```
f[x_] := xaaaa^2
f[123]
(* xaaaa^2 *)
```

Please remember, one should **never guess** the meaning of unknown syntax. Consider starting from the tutorial [*Patterns*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Patterns.html) in the document to learn how pattern matching works.

If you want to use wildcard character, here is a possibility:

```
Cases[{alpha, beta, mxyzptlk}, _?(StringMatchQ[SymbolName@#, "b*"] &)]
(* {beta} *)
```

If you don't bother to type the lengthy pattern every time, define a function e.g.:

```
wildcard[字符串_] := _?(StringMatchQ[SymbolName@#, 字符串] &)

Cases[{alpha, beta, mxyzptlk}, wildcard@"a*"]
(* {alpha} *)
```